# Local idempotents in a von Neumann regular rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, idempotents

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Recall that an idempotent element $e$ of $R$ is an element a such that $e^2=e$, and a local idempotent is an idempotent a such that $Re$ is a local ring. Also, a  von Neumann regular ring is a ring $R$ such that for every $a$ in $R$ there exists an $x$ in $R$ such that $a = axa$.

> I am looking for a characterization of local idempotents in a von Neumann regular ring.

Any hint is appreciated

Comment: What sort of characterization do you want?  What do you want to do that you can't do just straight from the definitions?

Comment: Any characterization in term of  maximal ideal contaning it or a characterization that is related to von Neumann regularity of $R$. Actually a characterization  that localness is hidden in it.

Answer (score 2):

In a von Neumann regular ring, local idempotents are those idempotents  $e$ such that $Re$ is a field. In particular, it is also a minimal ideal.